# Orthonormal basis . Can I have more than one basis for the subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces, orthonormal, orthogonality

Required to find an orthonormal basis for the following subspace of $\Bbb R^4$:
$$\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \\ w\end{pmatrix}\right\vert x-y-z+w=0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ x+z=0\right\}.$$

I know that to find the othonormal basis, it is required that i find the basis for the subspace, then I use Gram Schmidt process. Afterwards Ill normalize the vectors I get from the GS process and that should give me the orthonormal basis. **My question really is, can I get more than one basis for the subspace**? I got $\{(3, -2, 1, 0) , ( 0, 1, 0, 1)\}$ whereas my teacher got $\{(-1, -2, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1) \}$. Note: we both used different free variables.

**Also**,  If I used $x$ and $y$ as free variables and get my basis, then i use $x$ and $z$ as free variables to get my basis. They both are legit bases right **?**

Comment: @vadim123 I think OP really just asks for basis not orthonormal basis. This is what they write and both pairs are clearly neither orthogonal not normalized. (I had the same misreading initially.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of $\mathbb R^2$ - the real plane - since your subspace clearly has dimension $2$ and is therefore a plane.

Take an arbitrary unit vector at the origin. Can you find a second unit vector at right-angles to the first?

That is essentially the configuration you are looking for. It doesn't compute the basis vectors for you, but I hope it helps you to visualise the problem.

Comment: Yes I can. So the answer is yes, I can have more than one basis ?

Comment: @Izzy92 Indeed you can - the algebra simply encodes the information for an arbitrary two dimensional subspace (which itself amounts to a change of basis)

Answer (score 3):

Yes: any $k$ independent vectors are the basis of a space of dimension $k$. (They are from this space, of course).